# How to make Jupyter Notebooks Sharable to your colleagues

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-analysis

At my organisation we currently use a sql query tool on top of Redshift. This provider us with ability to save our sql queries and create a place where any one can search for a query name and look at it and its results. We can also give query links to each other.

Problem is since it is sql and complex analysis and visualisation is impossible to achieve. So we are thinking of moving to jupyter Python notebooks. I am not able to find and answer to something that is free / or low cost that can give the same wearability that we are getting from sql tool. In case there is an open source tool , we can also modify it as per our needs.

Comment: Zeppelin notebooks or Hue in EMR would be more useful for SQL visualizations on S3 data than Jupyter, IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 also another use case is complex analysis. was exploring jupyter for that.

Comment: Jupyter and Zeppelin offer the same features, for as much as I've used them... If you want to use Jupyter, though. Look at JupyterLab